# USB stick not listed by lsblk, but lsusb returns "Unknown UDisk"

Tags: usb, live-usb

I was trying to make a bootable USB stick by running:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=archlinux-2020.07.01-x86_64.iso of=/dev/sdb status=progress
```

No status was displayed and it didn't seem to finish even after several minutes of waiting. So, I killed the terminal window and pulled out the USB stick. When I reinserted the USB stick and tried to repeat the process, `lsblk` did not list the device.

However, `lsusb` shows the USB device:

```
Bus 003 Device 009: ID abcd:1234 Unknown UDisk
```

How do I make `lsblk` recognize the USB stick again?

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035). and, if you are lucky, make it work again. -- One of the first things to do is to unplug other USB devices, and reboot the computer.

Comment: When I use dd even the smallest exercises take more than "several minutes".